# Is this React and Axios then promise usage correct?

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios

I am using `axios` for a React project, and I was wondering if the usage of `then` promise is correct in this case.
Basically, I use `axios` to fetch data from the database when the component renders.

```
class Participants extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            databaseUsers: [],
        }

        this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this);

    }

    getUsers(){
        var users = axios.get('/users/get-users').then((response) => {
            this.setState({databaseUsers: response.data});
        });
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getUsers();
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.databaseUsers);
        return(** html tree **);

    }
}
```

What I observe is that the state of the component is set twice, once when the rendering occurs, and the `then` promise fires, and a second time when the promise is done fetching the data from the database and sets the `state`.
How do I get more control over this? Like actually wait for the data on the database, and then render?
Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to implement what you did with several components.
But let's stick to this example.

There is nothing wrong to rendering twice, as you don't want to wait for the response and then display output.

You can have a `loading` flag so you could show a "loading" code and when loaded show the output.

Or you can have 1 parent component that manages the work:

```
class Parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        axios.get('/users/get-users').then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                data: response.data
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <LoadingComponent />;
        }
        return <DataComponent data={this.state.data} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I want my state to be `this.setState({loading: true})` in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: yap, my mistake. Copy pasted :)

Comment: `axios.loadUsers` is a function that I provide? And where does `get` come into play?

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution.